# Who was the quickest player in the English Premier League in 2014?

Tags: football, trivia, tournaments, english-premier-league

There are some rapid players in the premier league but who is the quickest as of now (2014)? And how fast are they?

Comment: I think Theo Walcott's got the record on 100m sprint: http://www.givemesport.com/347454-world-football-fastest-100m-sprinters

Comment: 10.6 seconds for 100m...that is quick!

Comment: @20050... Should that not be put down as an official answer seen as you have a source?

Answer (score 8):

It's very hard to pick the quickest player in the EPL. It also depends if you measure the run without the ball or with the ball.

To sum up the answer, **Theo Walcott** is probably the fastest but it's inconclusive.

Measurements are being done all the time by several organizations. In the last measurement done by [FIFA](http://www.givemesport.com/416458-top-10-fastest-footballers-in-world-football), Antonio Valencia was chosen fastest football player on the planet. Other EPL players who also appear on the list are:

1. Antonio Valencia (35.1 KM/H)
2. Aaron Lennon (33.8 KM/H)
3. Theo Walcott (32.7 KM/H)
4. Wayne Rooney (31.2 KM/H)

[image: List of fastest players by FIFA]

The accuracy of these numbers can probably be disputed, since all FIFA has stated  that the data was pulled off from their own computers and tracking systems.

---

Another source is [Goal.com](http://www.goal.com/en-gb/slideshow/5299/1/title/goals-5-quickest-players-in-the-premier-league). Their 5 fastest players in the Premier League are:

1. Theo Walcott (22.72 miles per hour)
2. Kyle Walker
3. Jesus Navas
4. Gabby Agbonlahor
5. Aaron Lennon

---

According to [ftbpro.com](http://www.ftbpro.com/posts/ian.stewart.palmer/128144/the-12-fastest-premier-league-players), Theo Walcott is also the fastest one.

---

But if you ask Kyle Walker (Tottenham), he will present [this](http://www.101greatgoals.com/blog/tottenhams-kyle-walker-uploads-picture-to-instagram-claiming-hes-quickest-in-premier-league/) as proof that he is the fastest.

[image: Kyle Walker]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t51.2885-15/928479_280411068786687_1663339398_n.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I would seriously question any stat that has Rooney as the seventh fastest player

Comment: The last picture link seems to be dead. (IIRC I have read on some meta site that posting pictures using imgur - with the links generated using SE editor - should prevent link rot.)